# Bootstrap Navigation link breaks into new line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap Navigation link breaks into multiple line.
As shown in pic, Business Plan and Add Member text is displaying in different lines. I need to display in single line. How to fix this issue.?

[image]

Comment: You should post the HTML code used to generate the nav bar, as well as any custom CSS you wrote (if any).

Comment: Post some code or share live link so that we can inspect it.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your navigation In

> "container-fluid"

so it take full width of page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Add</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Plan</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Member</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Basic Navbar Example</h3>
  <p>Wrap your navigation In "container-fluid"</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap, there are some predefine css included, you can try look at the css setting in this website [bootstrap nav links](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar&stacked=h), with only image, it's hard to tell where exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add following to stretch the nav-item text into one line :

**flex-shrink: 0;** //this will the issue

> Full Example:

```
.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-shrink: 0;

  > * {
    flex-shrink: 0; // this is imp
  }
}
```